# Which protocols do mobile applications use

Tags: networking

So when devices access web applications on the Internet they commonly use https/ftp/smtp etc.. protocols. But which protocols are used by mobile phone apps to communicate with servers. E.g Which protocols would a mobile banking app use? Would it be https or something other than it.
If it is https then why would this be the case as https is just used to display Web pages in a browser? Or is https used for multiple purposes

The question might seem obvious but I just need some clarification on the issue

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, application-layer protocols and resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. HTTP is a very versatile protocol and can be used for many purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Application questions are off topic here, but there’s no reason why https could not be used. There’s nothing special about mobile apps.

Comment: Oops. Apologise for that. So https is not only used to display Web pages in a Web browser

Comment: @CSS_Mast If you break it down to protocol and port, HTTPS typically just means TCP/443, and that being the case it's a port just like any other port.  Sure, some are "privileged" (1-1023) but that doesn't mean they can only be used for one purpose - you can use any port for any reason.  You could run a webserver on TCP/1234 or TCP/65535 if you really wanted to, for example, and run an FTP server on TCP/80 for all it matters.